# PHP Postgresql return query results as comma delimited string

Tags: php, arrays

Using the following code, I expect a comma delimited string from the implode:

```
$result = pg_exec($this->db, $sql);
$rows = pg_fetch_all($result);
$indexlistids = implode(", ", $rows);
echo $indexlistids."<br />";
```

But I get this:
`Notice: Array to string conversion` and it echos `Array`

Got the same results using
`$indexlistids = join(", ", $rows);`

It looks correct, what exactly am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$rows` is an array of arrays. The *"Array to string conversion"* error come from the fact that the elements inside `$rows` are arrays, not a strings.

By example, `implode(', ', reset($rows))` should work, but will not show the expected result.

You could use `array_column()` to extract your identifiers before to use `implode()`:

```
$result = pg_exec($this->db, $sql);
$rows = pg_fetch_all($result);
$ids = array_column($rows, 'id'); // 'id' should be the name of your column or alias
$indexlistids = implode(", ", $ids);
echo $indexlistids."<br />";
```

Example:

```
$array = [ ['id'=>2,'val'=>'foo'], ['id'=>3,'val'=>'bar'] ];
$str = implode(', ', $array); // Array to string conversion
$str = implode(', ', array_column($array, 'id')); // Works
```